# Define a function that is an integral that takes a function as argument

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I define a function $F$ in Mathematica that does the following: $$F(a,b,P) = \int_a^b P(1-t) \, dt,$$ where $P(t)$ is some function, say, a polynomial?

More specifically, I would like to be able to do something like $F(a,b,1)$, $F(a,b,x)$, $F(a,b,x^2+x+1)$, and so on.

Comment: You've seen `Integrate[]`?

Comment: Straightforwardly and in much the same way as you would write a function with any other value as a parameter. *Mathematica* is a functional language/term-rewriting system, so it is trivial. What have you tried?

Comment: $$\int_a^b P(1-t) \,\mathrm dt=\int_{1-b}^{1-a} P(t) \,\mathrm dt$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I need more information. What would be the expected output of F[a,b,x]? In your question are you multiplying `P` by `(1-t)` or is `(1-t)` the argument of `P`. It is normally easier to follow if you will paste in Mathematica code in place of or in addition to traditional images or text. You can see how to do that [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/how-to-place-nicely-parsed-code-into-an-answer)

Comment: probably best to make your function take a pure function argument: `f[ a_, b_, f_Function ] := Integrate[ f[1 - t], {t, a, b}]` then usage is for example `f[0, Pi, Sin[#]^2 & ]`

Comment: I am not yet familiar with making pure function argument in Mathematica, but **LaVigne**'s answer was the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using `SetDelayed` and either of the following two definitions:

```
myIntegrate[a_, b_, fun_] := Integrate[fun[1 - t], {t, a, b}]

myIntegrate2[a_, b_, fun_] := Integrate[fun[t], {t, b - 1, a - 1}]
```

The latter tip was provided in a comment by **J.M.**

You need to make sure that the third argument is a function. Below are some examples:

```
myIntegrate[a, b, Function[x, 1]]
(* -a + b *)

myIntegrate[a, b, Function[x, x]]
(* -a + a^2/2 + b - b^2/2 *)
```

The examples above cover your first two cases. Below are three ways to write your last example. The first way requires defining a function `f`.

```
f[x_] := x^2 + x + 1
```

and then

```
myIntegrate[a, b, f]
(* -3 a + (3 a^2)/2 - a^3/3 + 3 b - (3 b^2)/2 + b^3/3 *)
```

or

```
myIntegrate[a, b, Function[x, x^2 + x + 1]]
(* -3 a + (3 a^2)/2 - a^3/3 + 3 b - (3 b^2)/2 + b^3/3 *)
```

or

```
myIntegrate[a, b, #^2 + # + 1 &]
(* -3 a + (3 a^2)/2 - a^3/3 + 3 b - (3 b^2)/2 + b^3/3 *)
```

All of the examples would work equally well with the `myIntegrate2` definition.